# Automation VSTS REST API to create new project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to learn how to use REST API, but I'm at square one. The part of not knowing what tool to use to interact with VSTS REST API or how to configure it.

Any help on like "you should use this tool" and "this is how you connect to it".

Small goal is to be able to just get a list of projects in a VSTS account I own and I can build from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to use REST API of TFS/VSTS easily.

Here is a sample code to list all projects

```
param( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
    [string] $tfsUri, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]  
    [string] $token 
    <#[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
    [string] $User, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
    [string] $Password#> 
) 


<# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately  #>
$User='' 
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User,$token)));  
$header = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)};  
<#---------------------------------------------------------------------- #>
<# 
$securePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force    
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $securePassword)        
#> 

$reportName = 'TeamProjectList.html' 

$teamProjectsReport = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head> 
<!--mce:0--> 
</head><body>' 

$teamProjectsReport = $teamProjectsReport + '<h2><u><center>' + 'Team Project List' + '</center></u></h2>' 
$teamProjectsReport | Out-File -Force $reportName 
$teamProjectsReport = ''; 


$Uri = $tfsUri + '/_apis/projectCollections?api-version=1.0' 

$tfsCollections = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Headers $header  #-Credential $credential  


foreach($tfsCollection in $tfsCollections.value) 
{ 
    $top=100; 
    $skip=0; 

    $collectionName = $tfsCollection.name; 

    if ($tfsUri.Contains('visualstudio.com')) 
    { 
        $collectionName = 'DefaultCollection' 
    } 

    write-host '===============================' 
    write-host $tfsCollection.Name 
    $teamProjectsReport = '<ul><h4>'+ $collectionName + '</h4>'; 
    write-host '-------------------------------' 

    $collectionProjectList = @(); 

    while($true) 
    { 
        $Uri = $tfsUri + '/' + $collectionName +  '/_apis/projects?$top='+ $top + '&$skip='+ $skip + '&api-version=1.0' 

        $tfsProjects = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Headers $header #-Credential $credential  

        $skip+=$top; 

        if($tfsProjects.count -le 0) 
        { 
            $orderedProjects = $collectionProjectList| Sort-Object -Property name 
            foreach($tfsProject in $orderedProjects) 
            { 
                write-host $tfsProject.Name 
                $teamProjectsReport = $teamProjectsReport + '<li> <a target="_blank" href="' + $tfsUri + '/' + $collectionName +  '/'+ $tfsProject.Name + '" >' +  $tfsProject.Name + '</a></li>'; 
            } 

            $teamProjectsReport = $teamProjectsReport + '</ul>'      
            $teamProjectsReport | Out-File -Append -Force $reportName 
            $teamProjectsReport = ''; 

            break; 
        } 

        $collectionProjectList += $tfsProjects.value         
    } 

    write-host '-------------------------------' 
} 

$teamProjectsReport = $teamProjectsReport + '</ul></body></html>'      
$teamProjectsReport | Out-File -Append -Force $reportName
```

To execute this PowerShell in VSTS or TFS 2017 or 2018 you can create a [Persona Access Token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate) with all scopes (all scopes required here to enable access to collection level information). You can call the script with you VSTS account as shown below.

```
.\GetAllProjects.ps1 -tfsUri 'https://youraccount.visualstudio.com' -token 'xxxxxxxxPATxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

To call the script for TFS on premise 2017, 2018 you can use either of below depending on your TFS is setup with SSL.

```
.\GetAllProjects.ps1 -tfsUri 'https://yourtfs/tfs' -token 'xxxxxxxxPATxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

or

```
.\GetAllProjects.ps1 -tfsUri 'http://yourtfs:8080/tfs' -token 'xxxxxxxxPATxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Project are listed as below 
[image]

More information on script available [here](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2017/11/ps-script-get-all-team-projects-listed.html)